# Cannot detect ES version when loading data from pyspark to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark

i'm trying to loading data from pyspark jupyteer notebook into elasticsearch.
it gives me this error:

> An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile. :
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   detect ES version - typically this happens if the
>   network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a
>   WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'

my conf :

```
x.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='_',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat", # get it from pyspark jar file
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=conf
)
```